# How to dynamically add a variable to ternary operator in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, conditional-operator

I am trying to pass a variable from my spring boot controller to a heading with a ternary operator and nothing seems to work.

```
<h1 th:text="${createEntry} ? 'Create a new Entry:' : 'Edit Entry no. ${id}'"/></h1>
```

returns

```
Edit Entry no. ${id}
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h1 th:text=${createEntry ? 'Create a new Entry:' : 'Edit Entry no. ' + id}" />
```

or

```
<h1 th:text="${createEntry} ? 'Create a new Entry:' : 'Edit Entry no. ' + ${id}"/>
```